# Row is missing while exploding a clob data in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to explode below data which contains a clob type, but while clob type is containing null, the complete row is missing out.

SEC is having a CLOB data type containg array data. While SEC is having null, below query is not giving any output .

```
select
      
      CRE_DATE,
      serv,
      rg,
      id,
      hos_id,
      state
      
    from table1 a,
    JSON_TABLE(a.SEC,'$[*]' COLUMNS (h_id varchar2(256) path '$' null on empty ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `outer apply`:

```sql
select
      
      CRE_DATE,
      serv,
      rg,
      id,
      hos_id,
      state
      
    from table1 a
    outer apply JSON_TABLE(a.SEC,'$[*]' COLUMNS (h_id varchar2(256) path '$' null on empty ));
```